# Computational Model for learning Computability and Complexity

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, computation-models

I was reading the book by Kozen-Theory of Computation. There is a statement that Turing machine is the best model for  defining basic time and space complexity because atleast for higher levels of complexity the definitions are robust  and reflect fairly accurately  our expectations of real life computation. I did not clearly understand the statement. Why is definition said to be robust?

Comment: A definition is robust if small changes in the definition do not change much. For example, it doesn't matter so much if a Turing machine can stay in place or must move each step.

Comment: I disagree with Kozen – the modern view is that real life computation is better modeled by the so-called [random-access machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine) or by its real equivalent (which allows some operations on real numbers). This is the model with respect to which we analyze algorithms most of the time.